# Shopify Checkout - Form Submission - page not reloading - cannot disable button using setAttribute('disable') method

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I recently found a solution to prevent customers from entering PO BOX's on Shopify, and there are a couple issues I've encountered and was wondering if anyone has experienced this before. I'm aware that Shopify has limitations with what you can do with the checkout.liquid page -> now I found this great function that creates an error message and prevents the user from submitting the form- Now when someone does submit the form, the button keeps loading infinetely, and what I would like to do is to refresh the page. Alternatively, I would like to disable the button - which I tested this method in the console by creating a new variable and using the setAttribute method to disable on the form id. It worked in the console - however when I plugged that script in my file - and then checked in the console - it would return null.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on('ready page:load page:change', function() {
    var regex = /^.*p(.O.|o box|ost office|ost box)/i;
    var fieldErrorClass = 'field--error';
    var fieldErrorMessageSelector = '.field__message--error';
    var errorText = '{{ 'shopify.checkout.shipping.Po_Box_Err' | t }}';
    var $inputs = $("[data-step] [name='checkout[shipping_address][address1]'], [data-step] [name='checkout[shipping_address][address2]']");

    var regexCheckFn = function(elem) {
      var $current = $(elem);
      var $parent = $current.closest('.field__input-wrapper');
      var $field = $current.closest('.field');
      if (regex.test($current.val())) {
        if (!$field.hasClass(fieldErrorClass)) {
          $field.addClass(fieldErrorClass);
        }
        if ($field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).length < 1) {
          $parent.after("<p class='field__message field__message--error'>"+ errorText +"</p>");
        }
        return false;
       } else {
        if ($field.hasClass(fieldErrorClass)) {
          $field.removeClass(fieldErrorClass);
        }
        if ($field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).length > 0) {
          $field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).remove();
        }
        return true;
      }
    };

    // Call regex check on form submit
    $(document).on('submit', '[data-step] form', function() {
      // default to true and will be set to false if there is an error to prevent form submission
      var isValid = true;
      $inputs.each(function() {
        isValid = isValid && regexCheckFn($(this));
      });
      return isValid;
    });

    // Call regex check on blur
    $inputs.blur(function() {
      regexCheckFn($(this));
    });

  });
})(Checkout.$);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your code prevents submitting the form after Shopify disables the Submit button and switches it "loading" state and you don't switch it back.

I would slightly change the code to handle this by validating the whole form on both input blur and form submit events. Then enable the Submit button if the form is valid, and disable if not. See example below:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on('ready page:load page:change', function() {
    var regex = /^.*p(.O.|o box|ost office|ost box)/i;
    var fieldErrorClass = 'field--error';
    var fieldErrorMessageSelector = '.field__message--error';
    var errorText = '{{ 'shopify.checkout.shipping.Po_Box_Err' | t }}';
    var $inputs = $("[data-step] [name='checkout[shipping_address][address1]'], [data-step] [name='checkout[shipping_address][address2]']");

    var regexCheckFn = function(elem) {
      var $current = $(elem);
      var $parent = $current.closest('.field__input-wrapper');
      var $field = $current.closest('.field');
      if (regex.test($current.val())) {
        if (!$field.hasClass(fieldErrorClass)) {
          $field.addClass(fieldErrorClass);
        }
        if ($field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).length < 1) {
          $parent.after("<p class='field__message field__message--error'>"+ errorText +"</p>");
        }
        return false;
       } else {
        if ($field.hasClass(fieldErrorClass)) {
          $field.removeClass(fieldErrorClass);
        }
        if ($field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).length > 0) {
          $field.find(fieldErrorMessageSelector).remove();
        }
        return true;
      }
    };

    // Call regex check on form submit
    $(document).on('submit', '[data-step] form', validateForm);

    // Call regex check on blur
    $inputs.blur(validateForm);

    function validateForm() {
      var isValid = true;
      $inputs.each(function() {
        isValid = isValid && regexCheckFn($(this));
      });
      if (isValid) {
        $("#continue_button").removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $("#continue_button").attr("disabled", "disabled").removeClass("btn--loading");
      }
      return isValid;
    }
  });
})(Checkout.$);
```

Comment: I have the similar issue that I posted on Shopify community form. Could you please look into it to see if you can help fix it? https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/adding-click-handler-to-checkout-button/m-p/2077295#M128279